# Change default highlight format in preview

Tags: high-sierra, pdf, preview

To highlight text in pdf files, I select the text and hit the highlight button:

[image]

The default was yellow highlight. Somehow, it got changed to a red underline. How can I change this back to yellow highlight again?

Comment: Adding this comment for those coming from google with the situation I was in: Preview in Mac was stuck on "strikethrough" mode, and every use of the "highlight" keyboard shortcut actually applied "strikethrough." The answer below fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Preview help mentions:

> Use highlight mode: Click the Highlight button  (so it turns blue), click the down arrow next to the Highlight button, then choose a highlight color, underline, or strikethrough. Now, whenever you select some text, the highlighting style you chose is automatically applied to the text.

So de-select any text in an open PDF. Click the *Highlight* button - nothing should be highlighted *additionally* in your PDF now - click the down arrow and choose a color or strikethrough.

You can also determine several different highlight colors in a single PDF with this method (here yellow, pink and underline):

[image: PDF with different highlight colors]

Comment: It worked! That is so counterintuitive, Apple should provide a separate button to select the default color

Comment: +1 The "_de-select any text_" part was what helped me, after having tried this method multiple times with some text selected.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that the Highlight defaults to the last font/type you used in the Note. Delete the notes and do again with the right Highlight

Answer (score 0):

I activated the Highlight button and, with that activated, I chose the new highlight color (yellow) - and whoa! Now the highlight color is yellow and I need not use the button every time, but only my mouse/pen.

[image: Screenshot of highlight button]